# Can solr indexes be reused while indexing in Elastic search V 2.4.0 or 5.0.0_alpha?

Tags: java, elasticsearch, solr, lucene

I have gone throught the some links like [this one](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=is%20resusing%20solr%20indices%20in%20elastic%20search&oq=is%20resusing%20solr%20indices%20in%20elastic%20search&aqs=chrome..69i57.12650j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8). This does no address my problem. In our case , we want to migrate to elastic search and phase away Solr.

So, 
1) Can we in any way avoid the full indexing  in elastic search for the first time and re-use solr indices as both at the innermost core are on top of lucene ?

2) It is even good idea to think about the same ?

It would be an one time job.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use Solr indexes from Elasticsearch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31377708/how-to-use-solr-indexes-from-elasticsearch)

Comment: @AlexandreRafalovitch : Thanks for the help !!  i had gone through the link but doesnot serve my case. I have mentioned in the link in the question description.

Comment: That's because the general answer is still No for whatever the specific use case is. The indexes are just not compatible and you have to do the full migration or reindex.

Comment: We have TBs and TBs of data and i am looking for options to avoids full index , as it would put a lot of load on our DBs

Comment: The look for help on the Elastic list to develop a new solution I would suggest. As far as your actual "is it possible" question, it is NOT with the resources known.